# What could cause a connection to a Google Cloud SQL instance to fail even with the ip registered in the list of allowed addresses?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am unable to connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance. I get the error: [MySQL] [ODBC 5.1 Driver] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XX.XXX.XX.XXX' (10060)

The IP from which I try to connect is a fixed ip and is registered in the list of allowed IPs in the Cloud SQL instance.

The machine that needs to connect is a Windows server with Windows Server 2016 operating system and can connect to other instances of Google Cloud SQL. We only have problems connecting to this instance. Another detail of the error is that the ping performed on my Windows instance returns total loss in relation to the Cloud SQL instance IP. Finally, I can access the databases using my local internet or another server.

I will be very grateful if someone can give me a tip to identify the problem

Comment: Could you post the connection code (don't forget to remove any passwords) for us to take a look. Also, do you have Windows Firewall enabled on the machine that's restricting any kind of egress? (not usual, but something to check). Is this Cloud SQL instance in the same projects as the ones that you CAN connect to?

Comment: This is the connection code. It is a code of tests that I did. I have already checked the Windows firewall and also the firewall configured in the instance panel. We had another instance in another project with the same settings and that was able to connect to this one. I appreciate the help

Application("Conexao") = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; SERVER=XX.XXX.XX.XXX; DATABASE=mydatabase; UID=myuser; PWD=mypasswd;"    

Set Conexao = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conexao.Open Application("Conexao")

Conexao.Close
Set Conexao = Nothing

Comment: Are there permission differences? Authorization differences with the Google Cloud Project in some way?

Comment: Where are these settings located in the project? We did not make any configuration regarding this type of authorization in any of the projects. The only thing that has been done is to register the IP address in the list of allowed networks. For some reason, it works for one server and for another it doesn't

Comment: Cloud SQL requires authorization in order to connect to it with a Google Cloud service account. Are you using the same service account to connect to both the instance you CAN connect to, as well as the one you cannot? The error showing a total loss sounds to me like you're being blocked from even trying to connect. So I'm thinking it must either be a network routing issue, or a permissions issue.

Comment: Maybe it's something related to the route. I can't even ping the instance that doesn't connect. We do not set any permissions on any of the instances other than ips. Both are instances located in South America in São Paulo.

Comment: Are both Cloud SQL instances in the same GCP project? Did they both get allocated to the same networking VPC? You can look in the details -> Overview for the Cloud SQL instance, and look at the "Associated networking" box. Look if the value in that box is the same in both Cloud SQL instances.

Comment: Hi, Gabe. Thanks for the help.
It was really a network configuration problem.
Someone changed the network configuration directly on Windows within the vm.

Someone on our team added the external IP of the instance directly to the Windows IP configuration without our knowing it and this caused a route problem preventing access to Google Cloud SQL.

I changed it so that the instance acquires IP automatically and the problem was solved. Thanks again for the support

Comment: Sweet! Glad you got it resolved.